# Could not load NIB in bundle but only if some other NIB already show up

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Teguh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/25C54619-04C8-43B5-9E7F-3744877A2582/Recent Contact.app> (loaded)' with name 'RCContactTableViewCell''
```

Often it works.

Often the exact same code doesn't work.

I have no idea why.

It works if I create the cell fast
But not if I do it latter.

Basically the code goes like this:

```
NSString * className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
```

The codes, with the exact same class, runs fine in the beginning of the program. Then latter at latter calls, for some reason, it doesn't work.

I made the code like this:

```
PO1(className);
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
while (false);
```

First time called work

```
2014-02-27 17:13:20.129 Recent Contact[33098:70b] <0xa5d13d0 BGBaseTableViewCell.m:(59)> className: RCContactTableViewCell
```

Second time called work.

Then I do something on background. And once that done do something on foreground suddenly it doesn't work. To help you see the problem I modified my program a little bit. See how exact same code works most of the time but fail on one line

So basically I called [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init] and it works most of the time, but not after something that happen in background.

```
AssertMainThread;
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //WORKS HERE

}];


[[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //WORKS FINE HERE
[[NSOperationQueue new]addOperationWithBlock :^{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //WORKS HERE

    }];
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //WORKS HERE

        }];
        NSDate * startPopulating = [NSDate date];
        NSArray * arPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople([RCABAddressBookHandler singleton].addressBook));
        NSMutableArray * arPeople1 = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (id somePeople in arPeople) {
            ABRecordRef ABPerson= (__bridge ABRecordRef)somePeople; //do not transfer ownership
            RCABRecordRef * abRRWrapper = [[RCABRecordRef alloc]init];
            abRRWrapper.abRecordRef=ABPerson;
            [arPeople1 addObject:abRRWrapper];
        }

        NSArray * arPeople2=[arPeople1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            RCABRecordRef * abr1 = (RCABRecordRef*) obj1;
            NSDate * date1=abr1.dDatedAdded;
            RCABRecordRef * abr2 = (RCABRecordRef*) obj2;
            NSDate * date2=abr2.dDatedAdded;
            return [date2 compare:date1];
        }];
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //FAIL TO WORK HERE
            self.allMyContacts=arPeople2.mutableCopy;//[arPeople2 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(200,arPeople2.count))].mutableCopy;
            PO(self.allMyContacts);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:strContactsReloaded object:self];
            PO(@([startPopulating timeIntervalSinceNow]));
        }];

    }
}];
```

You see that      [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]

That's what triger the loadNibNamed

It work on that first line before

```
[[NSOperationQueue new]addOperationWithBlock :^
```

It doesn't work after

```
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[RCContactTableViewCell alloc]init]; //FAIL TO WORK HERE
```

So something happen in between.

Comment: It all depends upon the `Nib Name`, you must be supplying wrong nib name, it works fine.

Comment: That's not the only problem.